# Reading source code, passing cookies and field data to site

Tags: java, facebook, forms, cookies

I have been working on this project in java I made for myself in order to improve my java programing abilities.

The project is supposed to read a list of first names from a file one at a time, then go to facebook enter the name, see what the first result is under the suggested people thing (like when you type a name in, without hitting enter it shows you a few people) and gets the name and saves it.

Point it so basically see what the suggest people for each name are just to practice coding.

The problem I have with this is atm I have it doing it by hand, using a the robot option in java. This is horrible coding and terribly inefficient and slow.

I am unsure how to read the source code from facebook though because

a) you need to be logged in to use the search option that has suggested people, meaning I would need to somehow pass cookies to it

b) the form data for the search would need to be filled in before the source code updates, since the drop down menu doesn't apear suggesting people untill the name is typed in.

Is there anyone who can give a code example of either a or b? How to pass cookies and read source code or how to enter form data and then get updated source good. I have been struggling with this for a long time now and can't find anything.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should read the docs before just trying something. The Graph API provides a search endpoint, which provides the functionality you desire (if I understood correctly).

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#search

If you have a list like this

```
Mark
Sharon
Simon
Emil
```

you should be able to read the file line per line, and for each line request the endpoint `/search` like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={firstname}&type=user&access_token={access_token}
```

The `{firstname}` variable needs to be replaced by the actual firstname of this row, and the Access Token needs to be gathered from the Graph Explorer for example (copy & paste):

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.3&

A sample request (use HttpClient, see below) would be

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Mark&type=user&limit=1&access_token={access_token}
```

or

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DMark%26type%3Duser%26limit%3D1&version=v2.3&

which results in

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Mark Deere", 
      "id": "717082841687658"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/search?limit=1&type=user&q=Mark&offset=1&__after_id=enc_AdAYbM71uirdENZCzBE26nNu3oBItX6Q69nDF1PMP4o14FZAhPipu5U5JVGooaFZA04NraNyzj759r59gRfRdVMNyDf"
  }
}
```

Then you can parse the JSON (use Jackson, see below) and retrieve the content of the `name` field.

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens
- https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html
- http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are in luck - the Facebook API does exactly what you want.

You will need a Facebook auth token and will need to do a request on the User service in their Graph API :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

You can use the Graph Explorer (linked from the reference above) to try out and see - if your application does an HTTP GET request to http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/Chris (or any other first name) and provide an OAuth token in the header, you will get precisely what you want.  (For the Chris query you get the author Chris Green, for instance)

Comment: How do you get a facebook auth token? Bit unsure what you mean about providing the Oauth token.

Comment: Facebook has a lot of info on this at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens - but you can get a short term (an hour or two) token just by going to the graph-api reference above and using the graph explorer.  In order for you to do any commands through that, you need a token and it will generate one for you (for your own facebook). That token is portable and you could use it in your GET requests in your program (you'll need to generate a new one every hour or so of using your program). You can extend the token to a long-life (60 days) token - instructions in the link

Comment: So, you'd probably use Apache's httpclient library for this.  It can make GET (and all other) http calls to the Facebook web service for you and return the results.  You'll do the GET to http://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/Chris?access_token=aaaabbbb - where aaaabbbb is the token you got from Facebook and Chris is whatever name you want from your list.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to query `/search`, not an actual user. Because you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook API is one option. Other option you can try is web scraping with Selenium or Geb. These are tools that provide web browser automation through an API.

See http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example